# Fixed table header and height in Material-UI@next (v1.0.0-beta.8)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In Material-UI@v0.xx.x there are props for table height and fixed table header, but unfortunately they don't seem to be implemented in Material-UI@next. Is there a workaround in order to achieve the same thing using Material-UI@next?

I've tried switching to v0.19.1 and rebuilt my table component using that version, but this leaves me with a new bug regarding multiselect (https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/5964).

Any suggestions on how to solve either of these issues?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the current version of Material UI (v4.5.1), you can just add the `stickyHeader` property to your table per [this demo](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#fixed-header).

```
<Table stickyHeader>
  ...
</Table>
```

Comment: While using stickyHeader prop, Ithe external css applied to the table Header is not working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding position: 'sticky' to your header **TableCell** components?

I'm not sure it will work with your version of material UI, but in my case (v3.0.2) CSS  class looks like this:

```
header: {
    background-color: '#fff',
    position: 'sticky',
    top: 0,
},
```

And then simply apply for each TableCell:

```
<TableCell
   className={classes.header}>
   {yourLabel}
</TableCell>
```

Answer (score 1):

I add the code directly in the Table Head component:

```
<TableHead style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", position: "sticky", top: 0 }}>    
  ...
</TableHead>
```